# Strong encryption done by hand

Tags: algorithm, encryption

One of the distinguishing features of a good encryption algorithm, is that it is easy to encrypt, and hard to crack. Are there any that are easy enough for average folk to remember, and calculate by hand, and still stand up to brute force attacks on a computer.

Imagine, a prisoner (with pen and paper) sending a message to another inmate, and the guards seize the handwritten message - and put their prison-crypto-cracking department on it.

Currently, I am thinking TEA is the best candidate, but pretty hard to remember I think.

Comment: Try asking on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bruce Schneier's [solitaire](http://www.schneier.com/solitaire.html) cipher is designed to be operated by hand using only a deck of cards. There is also the [VIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIC_cipher) cipher actually used by a Soviet spy in the 1950s. Both are cumbersome to actually operate by hand, though it is possible.

Comment: VIC cypher is pretty interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are examples of strong cryptographic algorithms which can be implemented by hand. For example, in Neal Stephenson's classic - the Cryptonomicon, there's an algorithm called Solitaire (or Pontifex) developed by Bruce Schneier for use with a deck of playing cards. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solitaire_%28cipher%29) is Wikipedia's explanation, and [here](https://www.schneier.com/solitaire.html) is the description from the author's home page.

Answer (score 2):

[One-time pads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) are do-able by hand and impossible to crack, unless the opponent gets hold of the one-time pad. Have each prisoner make up a bunch of one-time pads, number them according to some scheme, have them exchange the pads, then when transmitting the message have a set of cues as to which pad will be used, e.g. if you hand it at this part of the prison or with this gesture then use this pad, etc.

Comment: I guess that could work... but what I really need then, is a way to generate a one time pad from a password.

Comment: @BillyMoon: why do you need a password? it's not a one-time pad if it isn't randomly generated.

Comment: One time pad must be carried around, I am assuming it is not possible to carry it, but your solution might work if it could be generated. Hence, if a one time pad could be written from a password, it is like carrying it in your head.

Comment: @BillyMoon: ah gotcha. if you take that approach then it's not technically a one-time pad anymore, and it is susceptible to cracking. but you could definitely figure out a human-computable way to generate a pad from a password. A simple one is to repeat the password over and over but that is easy to break. A better one would be to repeat the password, but each time caesarian-shift the letters over by the value of the last letter in the password. stuff like that.